# How to transpile web components coded typescript and scss to javascript and css in Material You (Material Design 3)

Tags: javascript, typescript, sass, web-component, material-you

[Material Web with Material Design 2](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/tree/mwc), I could use web components like `mwc-button`, by importing module from unpkg  or transpiling (or bundling) to a JavaScript file (ex. mwc-bundle-button.js) from the NPM package.

```
<script defer
        type="module"
        src='https://unpkg.com/@@material/mwc-button?module'>
</script>
or
<script defer
        type="module"
        src='../(path)/web-components/mwc-bundle-button.js'>
</script>

<mwc-button label="button label"></mwc-button>
```

[Material Web with Material You (Material Design 3)](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/tree/434a7c2b33de01f001b3e86b1329e9abc997b49c#readme), there are still no NPM package (@material/web) at 2022/06/29.

I want to try some web components with Material You, but I do not know how to transpile the [repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/tree/434a7c2b33de01f001b3e86b1329e9abc997b49c) to JavaScript files.

I tried,

1. git clone [Lit starter kit](https://github.com/lit/lit-element-starter-ts) (maybe use Lit in material-web)
2. download the material-web repository in the [Lit starter kit]
3. `build` (maybe `tsc`) about icon.ts for transpiling to JavaScript files
4. `rollup -c` for bundle to one JavaScript file

Then, `TS2307: Cannot find module './lib/icon-styles.css' or its corresponding type declarations.` is occurred.

Is this the right direction? (Can I reach the goal by solving some errors?)

Or, Do I have a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

in 2022/8/31,
there is the NPM package [@material/web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material/web).

Then, I can use web components like <md-outlined-button>, by bundling (with [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)) to a JavaScript file (ex. bundle-md-outlined-button.js) from the NPM package.